# How do I set values for a Boolean field?

Tags: nodes

[image]I have a content type, I'm trying to add a field that's a boolean. I want the options to be yes or no. This is something I thought would be relatively simple however, I keep getting an error message. I've attached 2 screenshots. 1 is the configuration for my boolean. The other is the error message my site gets. Can someone help me. What am I doing wrong?

[image]